# Any solutions for offline OpenStreetMaps with routing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, routes, openstreetmap

Currently, we are trying to develop app with offline maps and routing (navigation). OpenStreetMaps looks promising (at least as an offline maps), however I'm unable to find any related routing API or SDK for it. I know, OpenStreetMaps can be used as tile images OR as vector data. But can this vector data be used for route calculation? Is there any SDK already developed with shortest and fastest route calculation? IMHO route calculation from raw data can be very time-consuming task and might be considered as separate project.

I also started to look for alternatives and found [Google native iOS map app](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-new-way-to-add-google-maps-to-your.html), however, still searching is there offline map and routing support. Any ideas and experience on that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OSRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSRM) is a routing engine designed for use with OpenStreetMap data. It seems to be intended as a web service, but it's open-source (AGPL) and C++, which I presume means you could use its code for on-device routing.

Comment: I'm a little bit scared with the number of reported open issues (95) at github. However, thanks for a least one option. Do you know any other (maybe paid) offline maps with routing solutions?

Comment: Also, it looks like OSRM still uses their server for routing (https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Server-api). So,  after long days of researching I came to a conclusion there's no offline routing open source solution at this moment. Also, I was unable to find any offline routing solution (both paid or free), so I assume offline routing is missing for iOS...

Comment: The number of open issues on the OSRM tracker may be misleading as most of them are not actual bugs, but feature requests.

Comment: MAPS.ME uses OSRM. Both are open source. MAPS.ME works offline.